# How do I mark a comment resolved with the Google Drive Comment API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm managing hundreds of comments for Google Drive in an outside application. I would like to use the Google Drive API to mark the comment as completed from this application.

I've tried this based on the Google Drive documentation which is a little vague on the topic:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/update

```
service.activity().query(body = {'pageSize': 10, 'filter' : "detail.action_detail_case:COMMENT"}).execute()
comment = drive2.comments().get(filedId='abc', commentId='def')
comment['status'] = 'resolved'
drive2.comments().update(filedId='abc', commentId='def', body=comment).execute()
```

But this doesn't change the status, nor gives and error.

Anyone know how to make this happen?

Note that I've also tried v3 of the API, but it seems like they dropped 'status' from the API all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly change the `resolved` status of a comment. This explained in the `comments` resource [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments):

> The status of this comment. Status can be changed by posting a reply to a comment with the desired status.
> "open" - The comment is still open.
> "resolved" - **The comment has been resolved by one of its replies.**

You can see that the "Notes" column explains whether or not the field is writable. The "status" field is not marked as writable so the API will return it if it exists, but you cannot edit it. As explained in the description, comments are resolved by their `replies`.

If you then look at the `replies` object [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/replies) you'll find that the `verb` field handles this:

> The action this reply performed to the parent comment. When creating a new reply this is the action to be perform to the parent comment. Possible values are:
>
> - "resolve" - To resolve a comment.
> - "reopen" - To reopen (un-resolve) a comment.

Essentially what this means is that to resolve a comment you have to post a new reply to it with `"verb" = "resolve"`. In your case you can just post a standard reply with a `content` like "This comment has been resolved" and then add the `verb` property as resolved.

**v3 API:** The v3 API changed the names but the functionality remains the same. Here `status` becomes `resolved` and it's a boolean, but it's still not editable. Now replies have an `action` property that you can set to `resolve` or `reopen`, so you have to post a reply that has `"action" = "resolve"`. It's a little clearer IMO and you'll probably want to use the v3 API anyway.

##### Sources:

- [Comments object v2 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments)
- [Comments object v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments)
- [Replies object v2 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/replies)
- [Replies object v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/replies)

Comment: Thanks, I've manage to get this working.